# View all Intellisense options for Typescript Prop in VS Code without keypress

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

So far in my experience, I have found that in order to begin viewing intellisense options for a TS type in VS Code, I need to begin typing the name of the attribute.

If I type "a" I see options which contain "a" but no others.

[Screenshot example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2DO6.png)

This is of course useful if I know the API well enough to have an idea of what the attributes are called.

However, if I am new to the API and just want to see a list of the options, I'd like to just see a scrollable list of everything.

I know I can peek the type definition file, and this is OK. However, it would be easier to see the options in the same place as I am declaring the type properties.

Is this possible without having to type in a letter (which also narrows down the search).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On Mac the default keys to bring up the list is Ctrl + Space.
Check the Keyboard Shortcuts in your installation of VS Code, and search for `Trigger Suggest`